# FFMPEG - Can't crop when using VAAPI

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to take an rtsp stream, crop it and then restream it using the following

```
ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 \
  -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -fflags nobuffer -loglevel error -hide_banner \
  -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi \
  -i "rtsp://192.168.1.149:554/Streaming/Channels/101" \
  -filter:v "crop=100:100" \
  -rtsp_transport tcp -c:v h264_vaapi \
  -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/compressed
```

The stream outputs just fine but no cropping happens. Any idea?

Comment: You need to wrap `crop` with a pair of `hwdownload` & `hwupload` or use `hwmap` if your GPU supports the feature.

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick thanks!

Answer (score 0):

crop not implemented for vaapi, just remove "-hwaccel_output_format vaapi":

```
ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 \
  -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -fflags nobuffer -loglevel error -hide_banner \
  -hwaccel vaapi \
  -i "rtsp://192.168.1.149:554/Streaming/Channels/101" \
  -filter:v "crop=100:100" \
  -rtsp_transport tcp -c:v h264_vaapi \
  -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/compressed
```